# Can I open a new terminal with a new binary executing in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I tried to write a script that opens a new xterminal with some binary file(not command) running in it.The whole script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

XTERM="/usr/bin/xterm -bg WHITE -e /home/ambuj/practice/myBinary"
exec $XTERM 2>&1 &
```

The script terminates without doing anything.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: myBinary is what?

Comment: myBinary is the executable of any C or C++ source file

Comment: Do you mark "myBinary" as executable (chmod +x /home/ambuj/practice/myBinary)?

Comment: already tried. "chmod 777 myBinary"

Comment: Did You consider including `myBinary` in `~/.bashrc`? All code of `bashrc` is run in every terminal You open.

Comment: Did you tried it again? Does it function now? It's clear the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use a similar script to make run a script and an executable. It functions in both cases.

- Case of an executable `/usr/bin/xlogo`:

  > ```
  > #!/bin/bash  
  > XTERM="/usr/bin/xterm -bg RED -e /usr/bin/xlogo"
  > exec $XTERM 2>&1 &
  > ```
  >
  > The terminal starts, so it does the binary `xlogo`; the original shell give me the prompt back, because the script finish its execution. No error are returned.
  >   (*It ends well because the xterm starts*).
  >   If I press CTRL+C when the focus is on the *xterm window* I interrupt the *xterm session* and the executable. If I close the executable, the *xterm session* finish too.
- Case of a script, that I make executable with `chmod u+x MyScript.sh`

  > ```
  > #!/bin/bash
  > pwd         # To confirm in which directory it works
  > echo Please insert something 
  > read a      # It asks to input something 
  > echo inserted $a We sleep for 10 seconds
  > sleep 10    # It will wait 10 seconds to exit
  > ```
  >
  > It runs, again as in the binary case.
  >   If I try to interrupt the script this will make finish the  *xterm session* too.
  >   It shows clearly that the *xterm session* runs from the current *path*.

---

So if your file is executable  doesn't really make difference if it is a binary or a script.

Classic debug checklist:

1. Check if you can run `/usr/bin/xterm`
2. Check if it is executable ( in your example with `ls -l /home/ambuj/practice/myBinary`).
3. If it is executable try to run it from the current location (directory) to see if it needs to be executed from a particular *path* if  it needs some file somewhere, or if it is compiled for your architecture...

Note that **if the execution** of your binary (or script) **finishes your *terminal session* will finish immediately after**, and it doesn't matter if because of an error or because of a  *natural reasons*.

Never forget that the error more difficult to find is the one that doesn't exists: so if your program is executed and finish fast, it will seems to you that your *xterm* will  open and close without doing anything.

Comment: yes @Hastur I checked it again with the binary(executable) that I deliberately made it to loop for infinite times. And it worked !!!.
As you pointed out in your post that If the program exits, then the control immediately returns to its parent terminal. I ignored this fact while trying previouisly in which the host executable was terminating everytime and hence nothing was seem to happen. Thank You for your detailed explanation.

Comment: [_"When you have excluded the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"_](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes#The_Adventure_of_the_Beryl_Coronet) Thanks to said me it was ok. Almost everyone before or after search an error that doesn't exists. By the way, to pause the script it's enough that you write a line as `read a` and the script will wait till you insert something and after it will continue _naturally_.  If your script is taking the input from a redirection you can write `read a </dev/tty `. Just for fun do `cat /dev/tty` [CTRL-D or CTRL-C to exit].